SQLAlchemy relationship to fetch most recent child in list for each parent
I have a table of Automations expressed as an SQLAlchemy model. Each automation may be run many hundreds of times. Each run is tracked in AutomationRun model. This model has a created_at field.
I have a REST endpoint: /automations which will return all the automations for a current user. I want each automation object to return a most_recent_run attribute which contains the most recent AutomationRun object for that automation (if any).
This is surprisingly hard to express in SQLAlchemy without (a) running into the N+1 problem; or (b) fetching all the runs for each automation from the database (incredibly inefficient in my case).
How can I express this relationship in such a way that what I want to do is both possible and performant?
This question is possibly related but the questioner seems to be looking for a one-off query while I am hoping to insert the property into the Automation model so that the most_recent_run is returned each time the Automation is returned via API.
I also saw that SQLAlchemy has support for something called window functions. Might this be what I'm looking for? I can't say I understand the documentation here though. My underlying DBMS is Postgres.

I am probably being wrong here, would select automation.id, max(automationrun.created_at) from automation left join automationrun on automation.id = automationrun.automation_id group by automation.id; get what you want? I am assuming 1 Automation can have many AutomationRun

Does this answer your question?

@python_user Yes, that query (or a version of it) would work very well. That's not really my issue. I can express the query in SQLAlchemy or SQL just fine. But I am trying to create a reusable model called Automation that can be used in a variety of contexts and will return a consistent data structure.

@snakecharmerb What I don't entirely understand about that and similar answers using subqueries - in the case I am querying multiple automations, is it not the case that the subquery will be run for each automation, thus leading to the N+1 problem?

This is another that might help.  Re N+1, this is usually addressed by using a loading strategy like selectinload or joinedload .
